# Why is $J$ often used to denote $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ in older texts?

Tags: notation, math-history

In older books, I've noticed that authors tended to use $J$ to denote (usually) the natural numbers and (less commonly) the integers.  Does anyone have any idea why that might've been?  A few examples include:

- Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*
- Herstein's *Topics in Algebra*
- McCarthy's *Algebraic Extensions of Fields*

Comment: Someone congested talked about the Jatural Jumbers maybe? :-)

Comment: I've got Topics in Algebra, Herstein uses $J$ for all integers and $Z$ (Zentrum) mostly for the center of a (finite) group.

Comment: @WillJagy, you are probably correct.  I'm separated from my copy at the moment, and so I wasn't able to corroborate my memory.  Rudin, on the other hand, does use it to denote positive integers (e.g. page 26 in the 3rd edition).

Comment: From the time period, I would be expecting either German or some roughly German usage that may not correspond to a real word. I cannot think of anything sensible beginning with J, but I am not fluent, I can read mathematics in German.

Comment: Maybe $I$ was already in use, and $J$ was the next available letter?

Comment: Advanced Calculus by Devinatz uses E for the real numbers.6

Comment: This is a complete guess.  Maybe because $1$ and $i $ form a basis for the complex plane? That might give a motivation for the next available letter hypothesis. It's just what I thought on reading the question and is a guess.

Answer (score 2):

[Earliest Uses of Symbols of Number Theory](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~tom/history/nth.html) mentions: "The second edition of Birkhoff and MacLane, Survey of Modern Algebra (1953) ... has J for integers."
[This answer](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.03/amanda1.html) to a secondary student's question says that is the earliest reference she can find and speculated the same thing as @Gerry.

Sorry, only answering because I don't have the reputation points yet to comment.

Comment: The first edition of Birkhoff and MacLane (1941) also uses $J$ (well, the copy I have is the 1948 printing, but I don't think it's changed).

Comment: @RobertIsrael, that's good to know. Can you find anything where it mentions why they use J?

Comment: It does not: just says on p. 3 "The set $J$ of all integers, ..."

Comment: Well according to the [Earliest Uses of Symbols of Number Theory](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~tom/history/nth.html) Z was due to Bourbaki in the 30s, and a wide variety of symbols were used before that so I guess it's not too surprising that in 1941 Birkhoff and MacLane didn't feel the need to explain what letter they used.